# Will .Net Framework projects become Cross-Platform by .Net 5

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-5

Scott announced tat the next version of .Net Core and .Net framework will be released and unified as .Net 5 in November 2020 just few months later.

So we have decided to port some of our projects into .Net Core such as our WCF services and so on but based on these sentences from [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-is-the-future-of-net/).

> .NET Framework 4.8 will be the last major version of .NET Framework.
>   If you have existing .NET Framework applications that you are
>   maintaining, there is no need to move these applications to .NET Core.
>   We will continue to both service and support .NET Framework, which
>   includes bug–, reliability– and security fixes. It will continue to
>   ship with Windows (much of Windows depends on .NET Framework) and we
>   will continue to improve the tooling support for .NET in Visual Studio
>   (Visual Studio is written on .NET Framework).
>
> There will be just one .NET going forward, and you will be able to use
>   it to target Windows, Linux, macOS, iOS, Android, tvOS, watchOS and
>   WebAssembly and more.

what does the real meaning by `If you have existing .NET Framework applications that you are maintaining, there is no need to move these applications to .NET Core.`
One of major gain for us by porting .Net Framework application to .Net Core is being Cross-Platform.

Comment: .NET 5 is .NET *Core* 5 with missing .NET Old APIs included. You won't be able to just upgrade .NET Old to .NET 5 and have it run cross-platform

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All they are saying there is that nobody is coming to uninstall .NET Framework from their machines; whatever works today, will keep working. This is to stave off cries of "you broke our perfectly working system" and people fetching pitch-forks.

All of the benefits, including (but not limited to) cross-platform compatibility: are in .NET Core, and it is absolutely correct to migrate to .NET Core if you *even possibly* can.

Comment: Thanks, so if we want to make our project to be cross-platform, firstly should port them to .Net Core 3 or .Net 5 in future?

Comment: @Aria yes, basically (note: .NET Core 3.1 is the LTS - so I'd pick that for now, *not* .NET Core 3.0): https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core

Comment: So the meaning of `If you have existing .NET Framework applications that you are maintaining, there is no need to move these applications to .NET Core.` is that the .Net frameworks just will be supported in .Net 5 not being Cross-Platform-ed and if an applicaton wnats to be cross-platform still need to be port to .Net first.

Comment: Yes, I mean the latest version of .Net Core.

Comment: @Aria important: no, those applications will not "be supported in .Net 5" *at all* - they will simply continue to run *in .NET Framework* - whatever version of that you are currently using. If you choose to stay with .NET Framework, you *are choosing to stay with .NET Framework* - with everything that implies. .NET 5 is fundamentally a different beast to .NET Framework, and you need to migrate your code for that; essentially .NET 5 is .NET Core, so migrating to .NET Core 3.1 is a great step towards .NET 5; there should be minimal work migrating from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 5

Answer (score 0):

You will get 10 years of support with what came native to that platform.  The newest is Windows Server 2019 and it had 4.7.2 native.  4.7.2 should be "in support" until 2029.